# Waiting on a process on Windows randomly fails

Tags: c++, windows

I have a project which is a compiler. I have an integration test suite for my compiler that compiles the sample source into an object, invokes ld to link it, then invokes the executable and checks the result. Each of these three steps is a fresh process separate from the test driver.

Unfortunately I am seeing random test failures because for some reason, when I come to link, the previous test has not finished running, even though I explicitly wait on termination of each process before beginning the next step. Thus ld fails as it cannot write out the new executable.

I *could* fix this problem by running each test in a new directory or giving the temp files unique names, but I don't want to do that since this approach should work and I would just be papering over the problem that I can't wait on a process to terminate properly.

Here's my code for starting and waiting for the process:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Pipe {
    HANDLE ReadHandle;
    HANDLE writehandle;
public:
    Pipe() {
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
        saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
        saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
        saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
        CreatePipe(&ReadHandle, &writehandle, &saAttr, 0);
    }
    HANDLE WriteHandle() {
        return writehandle;
    }
    std::string Contents() {
        CloseHandle(writehandle);
        DWORD dwRead;
        CHAR chBuf[1024];
        BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

        std::string result;
        for (;;)
        {
            bSuccess = ReadFile(ReadHandle, chBuf, 1024, &dwRead, NULL);
            if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0) break;
            result += std::string(chBuf, chBuf + dwRead);
        }
        return result;
    }
    ~Pipe() {
        CloseHandle(ReadHandle);
    }
};
Wide::Driver::ProcessResult Wide::Driver::StartAndWaitForProcess(std::string name, std::vector<std::string> args, Util::optional<unsigned> timeout)
{
    auto throw_last_err = [] {
        DWORD dw = GetLastError();
        const char* message;
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            nullptr, dw, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR)&message, 0, nullptr);
        std::string err = message;
        LocalFree((void*)message);
        throw std::runtime_error(err);
    };
    ProcessResult result;
    Pipe stdoutpipe;
    Pipe stderrpipe;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION info = { 0 };
    STARTUPINFO startinfo = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };
    std::string final_args = name;
    for (auto arg : args)
         final_args += " " + arg;
    startinfo.hStdOutput = stdoutpipe.WriteHandle();
    startinfo.hStdError = stderrpipe.WriteHandle();
    startinfo.hStdInput = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    startinfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    auto proc = CreateProcess(
        name.c_str(),
        &final_args[0],
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        TRUE,
        NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        &startinfo,
        &info
         );
    if (!proc) {
        throw_last_err();        
    }
    if (timeout == 0)
        timeout = INFINITE;

    std::thread writethread([&] {
        result.std_out = stdoutpipe.Contents();
    });
    std::thread errthread([&] {
        result.std_err = stderrpipe.Contents();
    });

    auto waiterr = WaitForSingleObject(info.hProcess, timeout ? *timeout : INFINITE);
    if (waiterr == WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
        TerminateProcess(info.hProcess, 1);
        waiterr = WaitForSingleObject(info.hProcess, timeout ? *timeout : INFINITE);
        if (waiterr != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
            throw_last_err();
        }
    } else if (waiterr != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
        throw_last_err();
    }

    writethread.join();
    errthread.join();
    DWORD exit_code;
    GetExitCodeProcess(info.hProcess, &exit_code);
    CloseHandle(info.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(info.hThread);
    result.exitcode = exit_code;
    if (exit_code != 0)
        return result;
    return result;
}
```

`throw_last_err()` is never called, so everything went fine, supposedly.

Why can I not wait on the process?

Comment: Have you thought about using Process [Job Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161.aspx) to ensure a clean state between test runs?

Comment: Pretty common question lately.  Surely the real problem is that you don't have trouble detect process termination, the issue is that the file is still locked so the linker cannot rewrite it.  That happens, too much crapware around.  Disable your anti-malware and try again. If it is Avast then uninstall asap.  The generic solution is to give whatever process has the lock enough time to finish its job.  Renaming the file can work too.

Comment: I don't have any anti-malware- I know they're all crap ;p It would be nice if I could detect this situation and figure out for sure which process is using the file, but given that I've literally just written it out for my own test, I think it's unlikely that some other program is using it.

Comment: I don't see how waiting on a job object and waiting on a process are different things here. Job objects seem to be about controlling several processes at once; I have only one external process running at a time (modulo bugs like this one)

Comment: `handles.exe` (available from the MS website) should be able to show you what executable has the file open.  (Though it might not work if it is a kernel-mode component that is responsible.)  `pslist.exe` can be used to double-check that your test executable is no longer running.  Using separate directories for each test is probably the best workaround.

Comment: Have you checked whether Windows Search is enabled?  That's another component that can hold random files open.

Comment: Hmm. So in general, I can't assume that files on a Windows box won't be locked open by random crap? Perhaps waiting on the process isn't the problem after all. I guess in that case the separate directories thing may be a better solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments, various Windows components like Search can hold locks on random files. This implies to me that in general, I can't assume that the file won't be locked and that therefore I should not assume that I can re-use it immediately.

Therefore I've decided that I will simply not re-use the intermediate files.

Comment: That's pretty much what everybody else does, yes. :-)